# How to skip user creation when installing

Tags: system-installation, root, users, passwd

I am customising a Ubuntu Live CD.

I want to skip the user creation step during installation and instead asks for a root password. Is it possible to do so?

My workaround:

1. create a user first,
2. Then `passwd root` to change the UNIX password.
3. Then log in to the root account and `usedel user`.

But I want to skip the user creation all together.

Comment: I would advice to use another operating system if you want to use "root". Besides that: skipping parts of the installer can be done with 2 methods: 1. you use a kickstart file to include a user name and all the other inputs for that screen or you need to remove the part for this from the software that is asking this. Ie. edit ubiquity source and recompile it.

Answer (score 2):

You can install Ubuntu as an OEM distributor, with the installer. That way it installs the OS but asks to create a user and it contunues the further setup at a client eg. But in your case this might also be handy.